# How to handle backBarButtonItem pressed?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller, backbarbuttonitem

I have almost done this in all the application but I have 3 views stacked in navigationController and I need to jump from the third view to the first view.
As I understand I can do this via viewWillDisappear only. But if I try this "jump" I will get the navigationController panel from the second View which with a navigation buttons which cause exceptions/errors.

P.S. Do not advice me to make leftBarButtonitem looking like backBarButtonItem. It is too difficult and I don't know where to find an appropriate image for it.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you have no choice but to provide your own `UIBarButtonItem`. You are not permitted from interrupting how `UINavigationController` works by default. That is, you cannot override the behavior of the back button. You must provide a custom bar button item and set it as the navigation item's left bar button item.

(As a side note, the sort of behavior you're looking for may be an indication of a poor navigation pattern. Back buttons should almost always back out of a navigation hierarchy sequentially.)

Comment: my another idea is to draw a transparent button over the backbarbutton. It could be simplier because I do not need a special image and I also don't need to know the exact size of this button.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say in navigation order your views stacked like top -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 . When you are in this position you can have a flag in your application delegate that shows you will doublePop when backButton pressed as below: ( You are doing this whenever third view appears in the order you mentioned)

```
MyApplicationDelegate * del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
del.doublePopEnabled = YES;
[del release];
```

In view 2 :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
         MyApplicationDelegate * del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
         if(del.doublePopEnabled){
           //Asssuming you have a reference to your navigationController in your view 2
           del.doublePopEnabled = NO;
           [del.release]
           //Use animated as no if you don't want user to see doublePopping.
           self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

          }
 }
```

Hope it helps.